# Umbraco 6 MVC4 plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I’m having an issue that I need some help for. I’m trying to make an MVC4 plugin for Umbraco 6.0 that enables me to  use my own controllers and views, inside an umbraco template – also using custom routes. I tried following http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers to the bone, but without any luck. I can’t seem to be able to load my own views into the body of the Umbraco template.

If anyone has succeeded with anything similar to this – can you post your solution, or give me a hint to whereas you found a suitable guide? Since I’ve been at this for days – a step by step guide would be great.

Thank you in advance, and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are my views.

1. Have you complied your solution so that your SurfaceController become part of compiled code. e.g "MySurfaceController" if you are referring to above URL that you provide in question.
2. Send you need to check the views inside Umrbaco folder since All locally declared controllers get routed to "/umbraco/surface/{controllername}/{action}/{id}"
3. Can you post what error you are getting?

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: Hi Jigar. Thanks for trying to help, but it's been almost a year since I had this issue, so I won't be able to provide the errors I got. I hope your answer will help some one else who might run in to the same issue.